# For each in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to echo out each date in my Array within a PHP file. Right now my code is

```
foreach ($result_array as $date) {
   echo $date;
}
```

which results in

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

How can I modify my code to show each date rather then Array?

*EDIT*

I'm building the array like so...

```
    $result_array =  array();
    $result_set = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `saledate` FROM `phoneappdetail` WHERE salebarn = 'OSI'");

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set) ) {
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: Show us how `$result_array` gets built.

Comment: Can you give a var_dump of $result_array?

Comment: @jonathanM I've added the code I used to build it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It prints Array because `$date` is array, modify your script like this:

```
foreach ($result_array as $date) {
   echo $date['saledate'];
}
```

Read more on how [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) works, it returns array (indexed, associative or both), so you need to choose which field you want to use.

Note from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> mysqli_fetch_array()
>
> PDOStatement::fetch()